# git pull fetches images as text

Tags: git, github

I am trying to make a website and have everything uploaded to GitHub. My issue is that when I use `git pull`, it doesn't pull the images correctly. These images are named correctly in the code and show up on GitHub. However, when I pull the images, they say this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:(some long string)
size 1467816
```

How can I correctly pull these files?

Comment: Those look like Git-LFS. Git-LFS is not Git: Git-LFS is a program that *uses* Git. If you just use Git, you'll see how Git-LFS uses Git, but you won't get your files.

Comment: so what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Presumably, install and use Git-LFS. I have never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add LFS (large file storage) functionality to your local git installation. Therefore you need to install git-lfs on top of your existing installation.

Find the official installer [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/installing-git-large-file-storage).

Working with git-lfs is basically associating certain file types in a repo with tracking by lfs. When adding a file of lfs-tracked type it will be handled by git-lfs automatically enabling you to stick to the git syntax that you already know. To add a file type to lfs you simply start a git bash in the folder of your repository and say `git lfs track "*.psd"`. Obviously following this syntax you can add single files as well.

The changes made to the repo will be stored in the *.gitattributes* which should always be commited as well.

Then you simply follow your workflow as you know it. You will be able to pull your files then just fine.

Please find more information on how to configure and use lfs [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-large-file-storage).